# Difficulties translating Scala Spark-Streaming code to Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka

I am trying to translate the Spark implementation to Pyspark, which is discussed in this blog:

https://dorianbg.wordpress.com/2017/11/11/building-the-speed-layer-of-lambda-architecture-using-structured-spark-streaming/

However, I am having a lot of problems because some of the methods in a Spark Datafram aren't available or need to go through some conversions to make them work. I am specifically having trouble with this part:

```
var data_stream_cleaned = data_stream
.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING) as string_value")
.as[String]
.map(x => (x.split(";"))) //wrapped array
.map(x => tweet(x(0), x(1), x(2),  x(3), x(4), x(5)))
.selectExpr( "cast(id as long) id", "CAST(created_at as timestamp) created_at",  "cast(followers_count as int) followers_count", "location", "cast(favorite_count as int) favorite_count", "cast(retweet_count as int) retweet_count")
.toDF()
.filter(col("created_at").gt(current_date()))   // kafka will retain data for last 24 hours, this is needed because we are using complete mode as output
.groupBy("location")
.agg(count("id"), sum("followers_count"), sum("favorite_count"),  sum("retweet_count"))
```

How would you go about making this work? I have successfully connected to a Kafka stream. I'm just trying to aggregate the data so that I can load it to Redshift.

This is what I have so far:

```
ds = data_stream.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING) as string_value").rdd.map(lambda x: x.split(";"))
```

I get an error saying

```
Queries with streaming sources must be executed with writeStream.start()
```

What could be wrong? I'm not trying to query the data, just transform it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `selectExpr` is a "query", but you're missing `ds.writeStream()` to go out to the console, for example. The "output stage" of that post

Comment: Is there a way to do the aggregations directly on the stream? Sorry I'm still a Spark newbie. I have looked in the documentation, but the PySpark-Docs leave much to be desired :(

Comment: Yes, via a windowed stream. The scala code is doing an aggregate on the location, and pyspark ultimately translates to the same thing